# How to un-version a file in SVN gracefully (without disturbing team members)?

Tags: svn, version-control

Variations of this question have been asked before, but it seems like the issue of disturbing other team members hasn't been mentioned.  In existing posts (see [How to "unversion" a file in either svn and/or git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695/how-to-unversion-a-file-in-either-svn-and-or-git)) the accepted answer is generally to run `svn rm FILE` or `svn rm --keep-local FILE`, and then set the `svn:ignore` property if desired.  I've spent the last 20 minutes playing around with this (checking out a repo in two places, deleting a file from one, then updating the other, etc.).  Here's what I found (I'm using SVN 1.6.16):

First of all, from what I can tell the --keep-local flag doesn't affect what happens to everyone else who is going to update from the repository afterwards.  To them it looks the same as if you had just done a regular `svn delete` (none of the subversion documentation I have seen mentions this explicitly - maybe it should be obvious that you're still doing an `svn delete` operation and that "keep local" will only affect things on the local side, but it wasn't necessarily obvious to me).

So there are two cases - 1. team member A deletes a file that team member B had no local modifications in or 2. team member A deletes a file that team member B *did* have uncommitted local changes in.

In 1, after the delete takes place B's file has been deleted.  He now has to recover it on his own (i.e. `svn merge -rHEAD:XXX FILE; svn revert FILE` to get version XXX of FILE back into the working directory and have it not be re-committed at next commit)

In 2, B sees a Tree Conflict on updating, and FILE now has a status of  `A + C` with the message "local edit, incoming delete upon update" below it.  At this point, I'm not exactly sure what the recommended solution is.  What I did is copy FILE somewhere else, just to be safe, and then ran `svn revert FILE`.  It ended up being unnecessary because FILE still exists unversioned in the working directory *with* all local modifications intact.  But I don't know how much I trust this, as I've had my uncommitted changes erased by `svn revert` in other scenarios.

**tl;dr**: Is it *really* the case that only way to un-version a file in SVN is to delete it from the working directory of everyone else on the team and make them retrieve it themselves?  Am I using --keep-local wrong, or missing another similar option?

Comment: I think your workflow may be the issue, why do you want to "unversion" a file? By definition, your `version control system` can only track versions of the files it knows about. when you remove those files from it's repo, it's only logical recourse is to remove them from working copies as well. Do you have an example of another VCS that lets you do this?

Comment: What about a config file? (i.e. Eclipse .project file). Anything that everyone on the team needs but is slightly different from one machine to the next.  So it shouldn't be in version control, but it got there accidentally.

Comment: I would be `svn mv`ing it and passing a memo round in that case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add all the files you are deleting to the ignore list ( easy with TortoiseSVN -> use Delete and add to ignore list option ) and commit that.

Now do the delete.

Another option is to do a svndumpfilter, as mentioned here: [How do I remove a file from svn versioning without deleting it from every working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633393/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-svn-versioning-without-deleting-it-from-every-working)

Comment: did you actually do the add to ignore list then delete? i tried it and it still deleted the files. only after i copy them to their old location manually do they show as ignored files.
if it really works i seem to need a more step by step explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Once a file is in the Subversion repository, it can never be completely removed. Sure, you can do a `svn rm` and commit to remove the file from the most recent copy of that branch, but the file is still there. Anyone checking out the revision before the file was deleted will see the file. And, you can easily find the deleted file by running a `svn log` on the directory tree.

There's not much you can do if you accidentally added a file that contains proprietary information (such as a customer's login and password) or is *inappropriate*, (we had one developer accidentally check in a gif he had in his workspace which later caused him to voluntarily leave the company before it became an involuntary act.).

Your choices are as followed:

- Take down the repository, then do a `svnadmin dump`. Use `svnfilter` to pipe the dump to a `svnadmin load` to create a new version of the repository sans the unloved file.
- Wait for Subversion 1.8 which promises to have an `svn obliterate` command. (Actually, checking the roadmap, it's not in version 1.8 anymore. Maybe 1.9?).

The `--keep-local` flag merely keeps a local copy of the file after an `svn delete`. The default is to remove the file locally from your workspace upon an `svn delete`.

Comment: Maybe my wording could have been more clear - I don't care about deleting evidence of it, just not having it in the current and any subsequent revisions.  Interesting examples and workaround though, +1

Comment: @danny: Then, doing an `svn delete` and `svn commit` should do it. Once it has been committed, it's no longer in the repository. `--keep-local` merely keeps a copy of the file in your working directory after you delete it. What happens on other people's working copies? When they do an `svn update`, the delete file will disappear from their working copies too. There can be a conflict if they don't do an update, modify the file, and try to commit it. However, that's pretty simple to fix.