# Remove directory from svn, but keep it locally

Tags: svn

I imported a project into svn. The project includes a cache directory. I want to remove the cache directory from the repo, but keep it in my working copy.

Bonus points: I have at least one colleague sharing this repo. It would be good if his cache also didn't get versioned any more.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What subversion client are you using?

Comment: Rename it, commit its removal, move it back. Your colleague will lose his copy when he syncs, though, unless he takes the same precaution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the cache directory get re-created automatically if it doesn't exist (in an ideal system, it would)?

If not, copy the cache directory elsewhere, then delete it (`svn rm`) it from the working copy. Then tell Subversion to ignore it in the future with `svn propset svn:ignore 'cache'` on the `cache` directory's parent. Commit everything. Then copy `cache` back from its safe place.

The other developer may lose his `cache` directory on the next update; he'll need to do the copy/update/copy dance to keep it around.

If `cache` does get regenerated automatically, just run `svn rm` and set the property.

Answer (score 0):

See [how-to-un-version-a-file-in-svn-gracefully-without-disturbing-team-members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654412/how-to-un-version-a-file-in-svn-gracefully-without-disturbing-team-members)

Each developer would use svn:ignore properties to prevent other users from versioning cache.

Comment: In SVN 1.8, you'll be able to set svn:global-ignores and svn:ignore properties at the server level and have it apply to user's working copies. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config