# Ways of maintaining separate settings for different environments?

Tags: django, django-settings

My django project has two environments - development and test. Today I carelessly overwrote the settings.py in test with the one in development. It took me a while to correct the settings in test, which could have been avoided if I have a good way to maintain the two sets of settings separately.

I was thinking to keep two separate copies of settings.py and rename/move them when needed. This, however, is kinda caveman approach. Are there any smarter ways of dealing with this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. At the end of your settings.py file, add this:

   ```
   try:
       from settings_dev import *
   except ImportError: pass
   ```

   Where settings_dev.py will contain the dev settings. And in your production env, do not push   settings_dev (just ignore it in .gitingore or your source code versioning system.)

   So, when ever settings_dev.py is present, the settings.py will be overwritten by the settings_dev.py file.
2. One more approach by setting the environment variable:

   ```
   if os.environ.get('DEVELOPMENT', None):
       from settings_dev import *
   ```

   mentioned here: [Django settings.py for development and production](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-settings)

I prefer the first one, it's simple and just works.

Comment: Haven't decided on which one to go with but I think both are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Split your settings as documented here:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments