# How to define two databases in django one for Production and one for Development

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a project that works on Heroku, I don't have PostgreSQL installed on my local machine. I want to keep running the app on my local machine using `sqlite3`, but when I push it to Heroku it will convert to `pg`

All I am trying to do is to have an IF condition if this is development then run sqlite3 .. but if it's production run then following command.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': 5432,
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': ''
  }
}
```

Heroku is working with `dj_database_url`

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

It basically similar to `Rails` when we define the gems for production and another gems for testing and development.

Comment: Try multiple settings files. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a local_settings.py file inside your project, and import it from your base setting file. This way you can have different settings for each environment.

This local_setting file should be included in your .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Do you use VirtualEnvs?

You can setup the `settings.py` like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': get_var('DB_ENGINE'),
    'NAME': get_var('DB_NAME'),
    'HOST': get_var('DB_HOST'),
    ...
    }
}
```

where `get_var` is reading the environment variables. These envvars are set by your virtualenv's `postactivate` file.

The production virtualenv postactivate sets the envvars DB_ENGINE, DB_NAME, DB_HOST with postgresql values

The dev virtualenv postactivate file sets env vars corresponding to the development DB.

Comment: Are you saying that in heroku these environment vars _are_ set for us, or do we have to something ourselves to set those in production?

Comment: You have to set the environment variables in your production environment.

Comment: interesting, where do we have to put the var name and value? all I know for now is how to create a virtualenv and modify the apps installed using pip