# How do I stop Django "python manage.py syndb" from adding tables to multiple DB's in Settings?

Tags: python, django, syncdb

I have two databases configured in settings.py, the default one and another called "local_mysql".

I want to create a model such that when I do `python manage.py syncdb` it is only populated in the `local_mysql` database. How is this possible?

I couldn't find much searching around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a database router, as detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing):

> If you don’t want every application to be synchronized onto a
>   particular database, you can define a database router that implements
>   a policy constraining the availability of particular models.

To define your router, its just a class with some methods:

```
class MyRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'yourappname':
            return 'local_mysql'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self.db_for_read(model, **hints)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'yourappname' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'yourappname':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == 'local_mysql':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'yourappname'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'yourappname':
            return False
        return None
```

Put this class in a file called `routers.py` in the same location as `views.py` for your app, for which you want to redirect the database.

Then, in `settings.py`, add the following:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['yourappname.routers.MyRouter']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need different setting files. Add local.py under settings. Then run python

```
manage.py syncdb --settings=project.settings.local
```

See the most voted answer here:
[How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django)