# Trouble deploying Django app to Heroku "no Cedar-supported app detected"

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been struggling to deploy a small Django web app following the instructions given [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). I've only been using sqlite3 to build my app in my development and everything works fine on the Django development server.  When I try to deploy to Heroku, I get the error "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected", but I think I have all the files required to get my app up and running. Been at it for days now with no success so I'll take any suggestions and help. Below is a sketch of my app, but feel free to sift the whole thing at my [github repo](https://github.com/ben519/landcrab).

```
landcrab/
    landcrab/ <----- main project
        settings/
            __init__.py
            base.py
            local.py
            production.py
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        db.sqlite3
        wsgi.py
    vcrental/ <----- my app
        admin.py
        ....
    static/
        ....
    .gitignore
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
    Procfile
    requirements.txt
    runtime.txt
```

In `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` I've set `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "landcrab.settings.production")`

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn landcrab.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt (used pip freeze)

```
Django==1.7.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.1.1
jsmin==2.0.11
nose==1.3.4
psycopg2==2.5.4
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.9
six==1.8.0
static3==0.5.1
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.4.2
```

For my settings file, I attempted to follow [this structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django/15325966#15325966)

Production.py

```
from landcrab.settings.base import *
import dj_database_url

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
# DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname')
# DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
# DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))}
# DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and finally wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "landcrab.settings.production") #Edited by me

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#Added by me for Heroku
try:
    from dj_static import Cling
    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
except:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: heroku stack:set cedar-14

Comment: Does the Python runtime work on heroku? [Found that heroku supports runtime up to Python 3.4.1 at this moment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes)

Comment: @dazedconfused see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support but also see my (idiotic) solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing.  I hadn't committed my changes before attempting to deploy to Heroku.  After committing, I was able to deploy without error.

Comment: Haha, don't be embarassed, you saved my day!