# Can I force Django staticfiles to load hashed filenames locally while Debug=True?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm using `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'offsite_storage.storages.CachedS3FilesStorage'` to store all my static files on S3.  On my localhost it's trying to load assets using `staticfiles` from my S3 location *without* the hashed name.  But my STATICFILES_STORAGE provider (django-offsite-storage) only uploads the hashed name version to S3. I want to keep DEBUG=True on my local machine, but I want my S3 assets to load the hashed filename version.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workaround. Create a file called **local_settings.py** and set a different storage. After, in your settings import the module:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Keep that file only in the local version of your site.

Comment: You can find different solutions here [How to manage local vs production settings in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1629770/974613)