# Django - raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-settings, secret-key

Django version 1.8.4

I was going for a django setup similar to one mentioned by "MiniQuark" here for my initial setup...

[How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django)

Here is my project structure:

```
project
  manage.py
  - project
    settings.py
    production.py
    development.py
    __init__.py
    url.py
    wsgi.py
```

My settings file has all main settings, then on "development.py" I have...

```
from __future__ import absolute_import # optional, but I like it
from .settings import *

# Development overrides
DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Then on my "**init**.py" file(which is ignored by git as mentioned in link)...

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .development import *

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(!z9pvx6&#4vm_wic3(n8*$m0bqer&^2913=1y!776e9b=-&#z'
```

Is it not possible to do it this way? As it doesn't recognise the secret_key mentioned on the init file?

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you mention, all the settings files are under a `settings` folder, not in `project` as you describe above.

Comment: I created a "settings" folder and moved "settings.py", "development.py", "production.py" and "__init__.py" into it and now when I try runserver it says "ImportError: No module named settings"?

Comment: I renamed "settings/settings.py" to "settings/common.py". Then I changed "manage.py" to read "os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.common")" and now I am back to the original error, title of this post.

Comment: The `init.py` file should be `__init__.py` (with double underscores before and after "init", so that python recognizes it as a module. Then your imports should work.

Comment: It is double underscore __init__.py, stackoverflow removes them when I comment for some reason. It doesn't seem to recognise my development.py file or the __init__.py

Comment: by the way, shouldn't it be `"os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourapp.settings")"` instead of `settings`?

Comment: Hi Laurent, yes you are correct. I had the "settings" folder I created as a sibling of my project folder. I moved the "settings" folder i created into the "project" folder, set "os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")" and everything seems to work now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad to help! feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)