# CSRF verification Failed - Referer is insecure while host is secure

Tags: django, django-csrf, django-1.9

I upgraded Django from 1.8 to 1.9. Afterwards, I get this error on my localhost after the Django admin login:

`Referer checking failed - Referer is insecure while host is secure`.

Everything works fine in production.
Below is a snippet of my settings.py file:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Comment: i guess you are using `http` in development. so the app must be configured for using `http` in your `local.py` (or similar).

Answer (score 10):

I had this error when I was switching from ssl setup to no ssl and forgot to remove last line from upstream configuration in nginx config:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host; #:8080;
    #proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;

  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Those lines in your `settings.py` file are fine on production because you're using an SSL certificate attached to your domain. However, on local you're probably using `http://localhost:8000` or something similar. If you try to connect via `https://localhost:{{YOUR_PORT_NUMBER}}` you'll most likely get an error like `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

The issue is in lines 167-168 of [django/django/middleware/csrf.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py). When you're using `https` on production, [`request.is_secure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure) is returning `True`...which requires that the `HTTP_REFERER` also be true or you'll get the error you referenced.

One solution would be to [adjust your `settings.py` file depending on whether you're in your local or production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15325966/2532070). That way you can add those three lines to a `settings_production.py` file that imports other settings that are common to both localhost and your production server. Your localhost would use a different set of settings that don't include those lines.

Comment: Yes. I get your point. before those lines I've specified in my question, there is this condition `if not ENVIRONMENT == 'localhost'`. Meaning those lines I've specified in my question only executes in production. So what do I have to add to my settings to prevent this error?

Comment: Just to check, if you completely delete those three lines does the site work on `localhost`? What's the error that happens then? The issue is that your `HTTP_REFERER` meta tag is not using `https` on `localhost`.

See lines 167-168 of [`django/django/middleware/csrf.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py)

Comment: I still get the same error when i comment out those three lines.

Comment: You'd have to show the rest of your settings.py file (make sure to comment out or remove any keys).

The basic solution is to remove anything in your local `settings.py` that refers to `https`...so I'd just be looking for the setting that is forcing `https` use on local.

Comment: I was able to fix this. Another library `django-cors-headers` i was using was causing the problem. I had to avoid that by adding `CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True`. And the problem is solved. :) Thanks anyway.