# How to deploy my django project online with keeping my settings of database and email password private?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings

I know there is way to do by creating local_settings.py and production_settings.py  but don't know how to use it!

Can anyone help me out through this problem?

Comment: Please find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15325966/3762142 and if you have any doubt then do not hesitate to modify your question

Comment: Yes,debug=false is there but how to deal with secret key? by using os environment solves problem? If it then how to use os environment  with secret key and email passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question. You have to export environment variable first.

```
$ export secret_key=wioj23423jij2
```

And in your code you can get the secret key using

```
import os
secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key')
```