# Recommended Way to Store Production Environment Variables in Django App

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7, production-environment

I have a django app that uses env variables for things like db passwords, django_secret_key, api keys, etc.

I want to use the env variables in production, but want to keep the values of those values out of git. What is the best way to:

1. Store sensitive production environment variables
2. Load the variables into the production environment

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question might be very opinion based ...

- You could for example read stuff from a configuration file which is not the `settings.py`.
- You could split the settings with `local-devel.py` which overrides stuff in `settings.py`

See for example here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings or this so question: [How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django) (which I personally find ugly ...).

I use salt-stack and put all the sensitive information in the pillars, but that might be an overkill for a single developer.

You can than use some state to set the environment variables such that your wsgi app can see these variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wound up using a combination of git-encrypt to save sensitive info in git and Fabric/ansible templates to load the sensitive info into my production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your files (configuration files) on your server. 
You can have a default configuration file in the repo for reference but the one with the production values you can "hide" using:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

## ***`--assume-unchanged`***

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>
```

In case you need to print out list of files marked with the `--assume-unchanged` flag:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

---

[image]