# Django setting up multiple configurations

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to set up multiple configurations. The idea is to have a central back-end and in the `site_settings.py` to change one line to switch between te configurations, instead of pasting the different configs in the site_settings.

`#config1.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from .defaults import *  # noqa


SOMECONFIG = NEWS_CONFIG = 'something'

MAPPED_ITEMS = {
    'Something': {
        'from': {
            'provider': 'someprovider',
            'app': 'test',
            'model': 'Test'
        },
        'to': {
            'provider': 'someprovider',
            'app': 'test',
            'model': 'Test'
        }
    },
    'Something2': {
        'from': {
            'provider': 'someprovider',
            'app': 'test',
            'model': 'Test'
        },
        'to': {
            'provider': 'someprovider',
            'app': 'test',
            'model': 'Test'
        }
    }
}
```

And basically the other configuration file is the same, just with a different `SOMECONFIG = NEWS_CONFIG = 'something2'` and ofcourse the `MAPPED_ITEMS` are different

The problem is, in the app's that I am using, it takes the config from the settings and not from these config files. I would like to have a line in the `site_settings.py` to determine what config file it should use

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15325966/1081569

Comment: It hasn't particularly to do with local or production settings, I'd just like to switch settings quickly while working on multiple companies. The project is a central backend and each company has its own mapped_items. The idea is to quickly set something along the lines of this `SETTINGS = company1.py`

Comment: Yes, but it's the same idea. Use the `--settings` switch to select the correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your site_settings file can be named as `base.py`, which is the common settings file. Then inherit the base.py into your `config.py`(dev.py or production.py) file

**config1.py (dev.py)**

```
from base import *
SOMECONFIG = NEWS_CONFIG = 'something'
```

**config2.py(production.py)**

```
from base import *
SOMECONFIG = NEWS_CONFIG = 'Anything'
```

Use this config file as your actual settings file