# Django settings module not found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, django-settings

## background

I'm trying to split my settings by environment by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15325966/766570).

Now I would like to simply run my test command like so:

```
./run ./manage.py test --settings=bx.settings.local
```

currently the following line

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bx.settings")
```

is available in these files

```
manage.py
wsgi.py
```

and so i removed it (since it's supposed to be read from the command line instead).

I also created a `settings` folder inside my `bx` app and added the files

```
__init__.py
base.py
local.py
```

to it.

---

## notes

note: the `run` file is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
docker run \
  --env "PATH=/beneple/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" \
  --link beneple_db:db \
  -v $DIR:/beneple \
  -t -i --rm \
  beneple/beneple \
  $@
```

---

## problem

when i run the command

```
./run ./manage.py test --settings=bx.settings.local
```

I get this error

```
  File "/beneple/bx/org/serializers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from bx.settings import DOMAIN
ImportError: cannot import name DOMAIN
```

in serializers.py:10, we got this

```
from bx.settings import DOMAIN
```

so i replaced `bx.settings` with

```
from django.conf import settings
from settings import DOMAIN
```

and instead i got this error:

```
  File "/beneple/bx/org/serializers.py", line 12, in <module>
    from settings import DOMAIN
ImportError: No module named settings
```

---

## debugging

the weird part is that if i put a breakpoint after `from django.conf import settings`, and type the following:

```
ipdb> print(settings)
<Settings "bx.settings.local">
ipdb> settings.DOMAIN
'http://localhost:8000'
```

I'm confused why it's not recognizing settings here as a module?

---

## update

I noticed that my templates directory changed. In my settings file I have

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
..
TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],..
```

However notice the difference in the value of `settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']`
 between the old way and new way:

*old way*:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bx.settings")
['/beneple/templates']
```

*new way*:

```
./run ./manage.py test --settings=bx.settings.local
['/beneple/bx/templates']
```

why is this the case? and how do I (programmatically) make the new way output the same result as the old one?

Comment: You don't import settings directly, but access them like this from `django.conf import settings` then `settings.DOMAIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've imported settings from `django.conf`, you mustn't import again from settings; you already have the settings object, you can just refer to `settings.DOMAIN` directly.

Comment: that's interesting.. but then why did it work before when i had `from bx.settings import DOMAIN`? did it treat `bx.settings` as an module rather than an object? and if so.. why?

Comment: No that has nothing to do with it and I'm not sure what you're confused about. Before you imported DOMAIN directly from the module; but now you're attempting to import the module, then reference that module again in an import statement.

Comment: ok i made an update to my question (re templates).. last update i promise!

Comment: `TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'templates')],...`

Answer (score 1):

`from settings import DOMAIN` tries to load module `settings` from `PYTHONPATH`, not from the module you already imported.

You could just do the following:
`DOMAIN = settings.DOMAIN`