# Setting.py and custom settings file issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am running Django 1.9. on MAC

I have 2 settings files settings.py (for production) and settings_dev.py (for dev)

On my machine I run the project with `./manage.py runserver --settings=myapp.settings_dev`

The problem is when I submit a form I get the **Error CSRF verification failed**. Request aborted.

This start happening from the time the 2 settings files got very different. For some reason when I run  `./manage.py runserver --settings=myapp.settings_dev` when there is a form submission Django gets `settings.py`.

I am sure that it is happening like that because I copy paste my DEV file in settings.py and everything runs good.

Any Idea how I can fix that issue ?

Comment: When you print MDDLEWARE variable of your settings, 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' is present ? Maybe you should show us your settings file.

If when you copy/paste in settings.py, the project works, maybe the path to your settings file is not good.

Comment: If I am in dev environment I don;t care about settings.py... The issue is that Django is using it.

Comment: A good post about multiple files settings : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django
You never don't care about settings.py, it's like your base_settings, and you override it for your developpement with a dev_settings.py