# Symlink causing Unknown job: gunicorn error

Tags: symlink, gunicorn

I followed the instructions given me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29371878/2532070

But the use of a symlink with my gunicorn.conf file is causing my startup script not to work, giving the `Unknown job: gunicorn error`.

I've tried using `init-checkconf /etc/init/gunicorn.conf` which returns `syntax ok`.

I'm guessing there's some kind of error with references or permissions but I can't figure it out via googling or searching here. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symlinks don't automatically work if you're using upstart.

The solution was to use:

`initctl reload-configuration` to enable symlinks with gunicorn