# Git assume unchanged for everyone

Tags: git

There is a file which was already committed and pushed to the repo.

Now I want it to be ignored after initialization, which means that everyone can fetch this file from remote but local change will be ignored  unless ones force-add it again and will not be shown in `git status`.

It is just like an untraced file except it can be fetch from remote.

I have had some try to solve it.

1. `git rm --cache theFile`. The file will be removed from repo by this command and can't be fetched any more. So it's NOT the correct answer.
2. `git update-index --assume-unchanged theFile`. The file will disappear from `git status`, which is what I need. But it's a local command. Others should call it manually. Also, the git index will change after some command so ones should call it again. It not quiet fit my demand.

Is there a perfect solution?

Comment: No, there is no simple way to do this. Those are your options. You should instead read up on [how config files are usually handled in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009/how-do-you-deal-with-configuration-files-in-source-control).